# Java.io.FileNotFoundException using File object

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, java-io

```
File read = new File("Numbers.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(read);

while(inputFile.hasNext())
{
    sum = inputFile.nextDouble() + sum;
    count++;
}

inputFile.close();//close the input file
```

I'm trying to read data out of the text file `Numbers.txt` and the following code compiles fine but I get the `Java.io.FileNotFoundException` error when the program runs. I've also tried entering the full file path but I might have done it wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: This should work fine if file really exists.  Probably file name is incorrect.

Comment: You are using a relative path, which will be resolved relative to the working directory of the Java program being run. It's always best to specify an absolute path when working with files in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Sure your text file is in the folder with your java file 
because you used the direct path .
and try this code check, if still not working .

```
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourTextFile.txt"));
String line = read.readLine();

while(line !=null)
{
     System.out.println(line);
     line=read.readLine();
}
}catch(Exception ex)
{System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
```

Comment: Wow thanks. It was the only file not in the folder with the rest. Program works now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
System.out.println("Full path is " + read.getCanonicalPath()
                   + ", canRead=" + read.canRead()
                   + ", exists=" + read.exists());
```

and then see whether the full path exists on your file system, and whether it is readable according to `canRead`.

If the file is a symlink, `canRead` might return true in that the symlink is resolvable even though the file to which the link points is unreadable.  To deal properly with symlinks you really need to use the new `java.nio.file` APIs.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me realize that above answer was what was wrong.